# Visual Studio Community 2015 & KMD

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, device-driver, kmdf

I have started working on a KMD project for exercise.
I have opened an empty KMDF project and started writing the km component.
Now I want to add a User Mode component..
Do I need to open a new project that contains both parts or is there a way to add user mode component on a KMDF project?

Comment: Even if it were possible, why would you want to try and put user-mode code in a kernel-mode component? What possible use would that have? Just write a user-mode driver, there is a UMDF, too.

Comment: I wouldn't, I want my driver to have a kernel mode component and a user mode component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After advising someone experienced with driver development in visual studio I came to this answer:
The user mode component has to be separate from the kernel mode component.
In Visual Studio it is done easily with adding another project to the same solution (no need to create a new solution).
Then, the kernel mode component and the user mode component, which are basically two different 'applications' can communicate with each other by IOCTL and major function.